# Nullpointexception while trying to draw a line

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have following two pieces of code

First Code:

```
package guicollection;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RectanglePattern extends GUIcollection implements ActionListener {

    JPanel panelForBackGround;
    JButton actionButton;

    void drawRectangle() {

        RectanglePattern outSideCover = new RectanglePattern();
        outSideCover.setSize(500, 500);
        outSideCover.createGUI();
        outSideCover.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void createGUI() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panelForBackGround = new JPanel();
        panelForBackGround.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        panelForBackGround.setBackground(Color.blue);

        window.add(panelForBackGround);

        actionButton = new JButton("Press me");
        window.add(actionButton);
        actionButton.addActionListener(this);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Graphics paper = panelForBackGround.getGraphics();

        paper.drawLine(0, 0, 9, 10);
        paper.drawRect(8, 8, 12, 9);
        paper.drawRect(6, 6, 12, 6);

    }
}
```

And second code:

```
package guicollection;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RectanglePattern extends GUIcollection{

    JPanel panelForBackGround;
    JButton actionButton;

    void drawRectangle() {

        RectanglePattern outSideCover = new RectanglePattern();
        outSideCover.setSize(500, 500);
        outSideCover.createGUI();
        outSideCover.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void createGUI() {        

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panelForBackGround = new JPanel();
        panelForBackGround.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        panelForBackGround.setBackground(Color.blue);

        window.add(panelForBackGround);

        actionButton = new JButton("Press me");
        window.add(actionButton);
        actionButton.addActionListener(this);





        Graphics paper = panelForBackGround.getGraphics();

        paper.drawLine(0, 0, 9, 10);
        paper.drawRect(8, 8, 12, 9);
        paper.drawRect(6, 6, 12, 6);


}

}
```

The second code shows the following error while compiling. Doesn't it has to draw a line and two rectangle on the `panelForBackGround`? What is the cause of this error?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at guicollection.RectanglePattern.drawRectangle(RectanglePattern.java:20)
    at guicollection.GUIcollection.main(GUIcollection.java:24)
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code and find out from where nullPointerException is getting thrown?

Comment: i can't figure out. It only gives the error message. I am a new bie.

Comment: Well in that case follow this link. This has very good tutorial for Eclipse Debugging.
www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm

Answer (score 0):

a null pointer acception here usually has to do with not creating the graphics environment correctly. Try invoking this method:

```
window.setVisible(true);
```

OR
it could be because you're trying to draw on a window that the machine hasn't had time to create fully yet. I've had that problem. Try telling the program to wait for the window to catch up by doing this right before creating the Graphics variable:

```
try{
Thread.sleep(300);
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
}
```

I know catching just "Exception" and not a specific exception is not the best thing but it's the easy way out xD lol. tell me if those work. if not i'll come back and help more later on.